# Questions about ethics and opinion based closes

Tags: discussion

How might a question on ethics such as [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31087/philosophy-of-character) be framed so as to work within the rules of the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things come to mind:

- "Is it important" questions are hard to answer consistently, because the answer depends on people's differing notions of importance.
- Questions that state a particular world view ("Do moral realists think blah?") or asking for if any are like that are more obviously objective questions.

  - This, try applying the question to itself: why do people question the motives of others? Some do it without realizing that they're doing it, some do it because they themselves have poor intentions. So, it all depends.